# Running a wine application when user selects a file

Tags: gnome, wine, foxit-reader

I've installed Foxit Reader in Debian with Wine. I've tried running a custom command in open with menu in gnome, but how is it possible to pass the name of the pdf file to the Foxit Reader via the custom command ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding this in "open with" should work

```
wine /path/to/your/application
```